# Issue on myStmt.executeUpdate using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython, updates, execute

I would like to insert a row by what I look for and split it . I did like

```
import os 
import fnmatch 
import java.sql as sql 
import java.lang as lang 
import time  
listingDir ='<%=odiRef.getOption("SOURCE_DIR")%>' 
dbConn = odiRef.getJDBCConnection("SRC") 
myStmt = dbConn.createStatement() 
tgFile=open(listingDir+os.sep+"FilePrecessed.txt", 'w') 
file=os.listdir(listingDir) 
for x in file:   
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(x,"FAP*.*"):     
    if '2' in x:      
      sourceFileNameParts = x.split('_')                
      dateVar =  sourceFileNameParts[1]   
      print dateVar
      myStmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO CONTINENTS VALUES ( NULL,NULL,dateVar)" )
```

I had an error even if this column has a String type on my table declaration. I did `str(dateVar)` before myStmt.executeUpdate for be sure that dateVar is a String but the error still here.

When I run this code I had an error on `myStmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO CONTINENTS VALUES ( NULL,NULL,dateVar)" )` it doesn't accept dateVar, why !!.

**NOTE** :When I use for example `myStmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO CONTINENTS VALUES ( NULL,NULL,'toto')" )` it's work with me

How can I fix this problem please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

`myStmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO CONTINENTS VALUES ( NULL,NULL," + dateVar + ")" )`

Comment: Really bad idea to construct SQL by concatenating unverified variables into the query. Doesn't Jython have parameterized prepared statements?

Comment: His answer is work well but I am not sure if it's a best pratice. do you have another idea ?

Comment: i dont know jython, probably there is something more elegant.

Comment: Anywhy your answer is working well , thanks @SajanChandran